# Here i was trying to implement jcplayer

Tags: android

```
ArrayList<JcAudio> arrayListSongsName = new ArrayList<JcAudio>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    jcPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.jcplayer);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

`these audio`
jcAudios.add(JcAudio.createFromURL("This First song","https://www.llll.com"));
jcAudios.add(JcAudio.createFromURL("This 2nd song","https://www.llll.com"));
jcAudios.add(JcAudio.createFromURL("This 3rd song","https://www.llll.com"));
jcAudios.add(JcAudio.createFromURL("This fourth song","https://www.llll.com"))

```
}
```

}

i want to show list in listview and play every songs by using listview.onset for each song```